# Way to import file using insert_update mode in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, file, import, insert-update

In db2, data from file can be imported with 'import' providing insert_update mode to do insert if record doesn't exist and update if exist.

Is there a way to import/load data from a file into a table such that records from file are inserted if they do not exist and updated if they do exist.

The only way I could figure out is to use bulk load with merge through intermediate/temporary table and then use that table to insert-update into target table.

With this approach there may be performance issue as all data is first loaded into temporary table. Please advise if there is way to do this without creating temporary table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SSIS.
In your data flow you would perform a lookup to see if record exists already, if so send it down an update code path (which will probably involve using a staging update then joing the two). If it doesn't exist perform an insert.

Along the lines of https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/9e14507d-2a30-403b-98f5-a6d2468b384e/update-else-insert-ssis-record

Comment: Thank you for response. Using SSIS may be useful if I am doing it manually using some tool. Now I have that in java code where based on logic the file is imported as db2 import from ... of ... insert into table or with db2 import from ... of ... insert_update into table. With RDBM change to MS SQL server, I am trying to see if there is any transact SQL provision in MS SQL server to import file to table as I requested in my post.